# Использование conda и python вместе

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

Здравствуйте.

Есть необходимость использовать [numpy-mkl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-mkl), а установить его на Ubuntu можно при помощи [conda](https://conda.io/docs/index.html). Но этот скрипт будет использоваться совместно с вэб приложением.

Не совсем понимаю, как это должно взаимодействовать.

Нужно, чтобы вэб приложение работало на python3.5, а скрипт, который находится в `utils.py` и вызывается из `views.py` работал, используя библиотеки, установленные при помощи `conda`.

Как правильно решить?

Comment: А можно и просто установить, без помощи conda.

Comment: Пробовали просто установить с помощью conda и вызвать из приложения?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, нету numpy-mkl на ubuntu в репозиториях. Из всего что смог нагуглить, это использование anaconda.

Comment: @insolor, пишет, что нет таких модулей.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, попробуйте просто через `pip3 install numpy-mkl` установить. Еще вопрос, используете виртуальное окружение для приложения?

Comment: И еще, вам принципиально нужен пакет numpy-mkl, или просто numpy подойдет?

Comment: @insolor, в конкретном скрипте написанном на винде, уже используется mkl, а без него скрипт не должен работать.
Использую Dockfile

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, ок, попробую посмотреть.